# is it possible to have two curl_init

Tags: php, json, curl

hi ive been trying to run this code but iam getting page isn't working not even an error can somoene point me to the right direction? thanks

```
<?php
       $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://security.voluum.com/login");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Basic plFubTHhcl93MzA4QHJJkQ9vqmNvwTpMNYYUIz5kcm9s"; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    $res_decoded = json_decode($result);
    echo $res_decoded->token;
    $tok = $res_decoded->token;

     $sh = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($sh, CURLOPT_URL, "https://reports.voluum.com/report?from=2016-11-24T00%3A00%3A00Z&to=2016-11-26T00%3A00%3A00Z&tz=Europe%2FWarsaw&sort=visits&direction=desc&columns=campaignName&columns=visits&columns=clicks&columns=conversions&columns=revenue&columns=cost&columns=profit&columns=cpv&columns=ctr&columns=cr&columns=cv&columns=roi&columns=epv&columns=epc&columns=ap&columns=errors&groupBy=campaign&offset=0&limit=100&include=active");
    curl_setopt($sh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($sh, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


    $header = array();
    $header[] = "Cwauth-Token: " . $tok; 
    curl_setopt($, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $results = curl_exec($sh);
    if (curl_errno($sh)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($sh);
    }

    echo $results;
    curl_close ($ch);
    curl_close ($sh);
?>
```

every time the page refreshes the token changes so i need to put a dynamic token in the second header. i don't know if i'am doing the right thing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the response, i solved the problem my self got a mistake in the variable name i put headers on the second array instead of header :D